# How do I add new hard drive and install Win 7 without removing old drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I am getting SSD drives in raid0 and plan to install Windows 7 Ultimate. I already have Windows 7 Ultimate N installed on my old drive, and I want to keep my old drive intact because I have been a bit lazy and not yet cleaned out old documents.

Is there anything I need to consider to make my new drives boot while still having the old drive installed and ready for access?

Thanks,
Statement

Answer (score 2):

That should definitely be possible, the new installation of Windows 7 will alter the boot loader (might not be the correct term) to boot your machine from the new drive as opposed to the old. You may need to convince the installer to install it onto your new drive though and not to repair / re-install onto your old drive, this should be possible through the custom/advanced options on installation.

Comment: +1 Also, note that if it does its job correctly it will probably set you up to dual-boot with both drives (defaulting to boot in to the new install).